# SQL Server - 2008 Format vs Convert

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've always used convert for date formatting, see below. As a new SQL user I see that you can also use FORMAT, see below. I realize that convert function converts your data into a string but when date formatting which is best to use?

```
FORMAT(getdate(), 'MM/dd/yy') AS [MM/DD/YY],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 1) AS [MM/DD/YY]
```

Comment: One point is that `convert()`’s codes are not exactly intuitive. `format()` is similar to Excel’s `TEXT()` function and custom number format, so it’s both more intuitive and familiar to many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, it depends.  Personally, I try not do to formatting conversions in the database unless it's absolutely necessary; keep your data as a date, and let your app do it.

That being said, FORMAT lets you do some nifty things for different locales at the expense of having the CLR enabled; CONVERT doesn't require the CLR, and can do most of the same work.

Comment: I agree that this sort of thing is probably best left to the application, but in Australia we don’t use the US date format, and the ISO8601 format is unfamiliar. For that reason, I suggest formatting dates at an early stage, using something like `'dd MMM yyyy'`, which is readable and unambiguous, so less likely to cause confusion.